# VirtualBox appliance import locks up system

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint, virtualization

I have a Windows Vista x64 appliance that I am trying to import into the Open Source Edition of VirtualBox on Linux Mint 11 x86-64. The **ovf** file is 21.3 GB in size.

The problem I am having is that every time I attempt to import said appliance, Virtual Box slowly begins to consume all 8 GB of RAM that I have in the system; at which point, the OS locks up. Would limiting the amount of memory the VirtualBox process can *use* be the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with respect to an `.ova` file. When I checked the "Appliance settings", I was able to adjust the amount of memory RAM and other stuff.

The key point is that by the time I noticed it was using 2 CPUs instead of one (because I only have one), it stopped consuming all the host RAM.